# Is mocking DbSet<T>.Find() on Generic the right way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In C# and EFCore, I'm using the following to mock DbSet querables:

```
public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

        var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

        dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));

        return dbSet.Object;
    }
```

That works in a number of scenarios, but I don't have support for the EF .Find() method.

I thought to add it somewhat like so:

```
dbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<int>((s) => sourceList.Where(x => x.ID == s));
```

... but with T being a generic, I can't rely on the ID property to check it.

Two workarounds I've considered:

#1: Change the signature's where T : class to some sort of where T : IFindable I use .ID as a property consistently, so that'd work, but then requires I add a bunch of IFinables to my non-testable classes, which is ugly, or

#2: Enter a callback that uses reflection to read field name/values, looking for an ID field and matching the value

#2 is likely what I'll do. It's ugly but at least it's contained within this test helper and doesn't require pushbacks to non-test code.

Does anyone have a more clever way to handle it?

Comment: have you looked at the EFCore in memory provider? this may help as it will possibly negate the need to mock out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @cookee89 IMHO, the in-memory provider is horrible both for unit and for integration testing, since it doesn't do the same that a "real" (quote that) provider does, except for the most basic operations

Comment: You could have some middleground where you check the type of `T`. `sourceList.OfType<IFindable>().Where(x => x.ID == s)`. Then you only need the interface on testable classes

Comment: @Jcl mocking a DbSet is worse - it doesn't provide even the most basic operations. Besides, a mocked DbSet isn't meant to provide a high-fidelity substitute either. The in-memory provider is OK for simple testing. For more complex testing the SQLite provider in in-memory configuration is better. Nothing replaces using the *actual* target database for integration testing. No amount of mocking can replace generating and testing the actual SQL queries.

Comment: @FrankR Consider using the in-memory EF Core provider for simple queries and modifications, the SQLite provider with in-memory storage for more complex queries. What you actually need to do is test the *rest* of your code without using a concrete database. You can do that easily by having your DbContext target a mock database.  What you're trying to do right now is build a new EF Core provider targeting your mocking library. One could say you're unit-testing EF Core itself, not your application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yup, I agree... I *still* abstract to repositories [and yes, I know a DbSet is a repository) and that's what I mock, so I don't have to mock everything on a DbSet and just the limited functionality my repositories offer. And yes, for integration testing, SQLite and/or an ad-hoc SQL Server Express launched on a temporary docker container

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There's no desire to test EFcore itself. Some tests require a real database, some don't. If testing integration between two services, a DB might not be necessary. However, for DAL or full api stack call testing, then every service, component and dependency is needed. How do you setup your devops infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, using in-memory provider is the recommended approach.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/

> We use test doubles for internal testing of EF Core. However, we never try to mock DbContext or IQueryable. Doing so is difficult, cumbersome, and fragile. Don't do it.

---

If you want to continue mocking, you can try this:

```cs
dbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(id => (T)sourceList.OfType<IFindable>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id));
```

That way you only need to implement `IFindable` on classes that you are testing.

Additionally, I would have called `IFindable` `IEntity`

Comment: This requires adding interfaces on entities just to allow mocking of DbSet, which has *nothing* to do with the entities themselves. Using the in-memory EF Core provider is easier

Comment: I do agree that there may be better ways than to mock out the DbSet. My goal was to provide a workaround that fixed the example provided in the question. I will add a sentence that recommends  in-memory first.